# How to redirect the output of a command to an already existing file without deleting its contents?

Tags: shell, command-line, text-processing, files, io-redirection

I am making a backup of some files and am creating a checksum file, `checksums.txt`, to later check the integrity of my data. However pasting each checksum manually into the file is inconvenient since my backup consists of hundreds of files, so asking around I got the suggestion to simplify the process by redirecting the output to the checksum file:

```
$ md5sum file > checksums.txt
```

or

```
$ sha512sum file > checksums.txt
```

However doing this **replaces** the contents of the `checksums.txt` file with the checksum of, in this example, the `file` file; I would like, instead, to **append** the checksum of `file` to `checksums.txt` without deleting its contents. So my question is: **how do I do this?**

Just one more thing. Since I am a basic user, try (only if possible) to make easy-to-follow suggestions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to append  to a file you have to use `>>`.

So your examples would be

```
$ md5sum file >> checksums.txt
```

and

```
$ sha512sum file >> checksums.txt
```

Comment: Isn't it wonderful when the answer is simpler than the question?  :)

Answer (score 11):

Beside the `>>` operator to open the file in append mode [as answered by @Thomas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237051), an other option is to open the file with the `>` operator, but only once and leave it open for the two commands:

```
exec 3> checksums.txt
```

Would open (and truncate) the file on file descriptor 3, and then:

```
md5sum file1 >&3
```

Would write the md5sum of file1 in there.

```
md5sum file2 >&3
```

(when run from that same shell), would append the file2 md5sum.

Then, you can do:

```
exec 3>&-
```

to close that file descriptor. You can also do the same with stdout (file descriptor 1, the default for the  `>` operator), by redirecting a whole *command group*:

```
{ md5sum file1; md5sum file2; } > checksums.txt
```

Or using a *subshell* instead of a *command group*:

```
(md5sum file1; md5sum file2) > checksums.txt
```